# Use if statement in 1 XSLT file to transform 2 different types of XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to use a single XSLT file to transform 2 (or more) different types of XML files.

I was hoping there would be some way to perform a check for the type of XML file by checking its "id" value and then run the corresponding transformation.

For example,

**XML file 1:**

```html
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<file1 id="123">
 <key>
            <uuid>123456</uuid>
 </key>
</file1>
```

**XML file 2:**

```html
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<file2 id="456">
    <house>
        <doors>1</doors>
        <windows>4</windows>
    </house>
</file2>
```

**XSLT file:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:template match="/"> 


<html> 
<body> 
    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="@id = 123">
        // do something
        </xsl:when>
    
        <xsl:when test="@id = 456">
        // do something else
        </xsl:when>
    
        <xsl:otherwise>
        // exception message
        </xsl:otherwise>
    
    </xsl:choose>
</body> 
</html> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML files will all have the same "id" in their root but I can't figure out how to query the root for the "id" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch an attribute on the root element (regardless what the root element *is*), use `/*/@id`.

```xml
<xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="/*/@id = 123">
        // do something
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:when test="/*/@id = 456">
        // do something else
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
        // exception message
    </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was hoping for! Thank you @markusk!

I couldn't quite get it to work on mine though, this is my exact XML file:

`<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<ficha_42 id="ficha_19" version="201912191739">`

So `<xsl:when test="/*/@id = ficha_19">` should work shouldn't it?

Comment: You're missing some quotes: that should be `<xsl:when test="/*/@id = 'ficha_19'">`. Without the quotes, you're checking if the attribute `id` has the same value as the child element `ficha_19`, instead of checking if it is the string literal `'ficha_19'`.

Comment: @chewflow Happy to help! :-)